Using chunks to upload huge file into lambda
I am trying to upload huge parquet file from s3 using lambda function in aws. As optimisation,because there is memory issue in lambda, i tried to divide received data into chunks. This is the code of the function :
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
import pandas as pd
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def process_object(bucket_name, object_prefix, flow_name, columns_to_keep, chunk_size=100_000):
    rows = []

    # Lire le fichier Parquet en morceaux avec awswrangler
    dfs = wr.s3.read_parquet(
        path=f"s3://{bucket_name}/{object_prefix}",
        columns=columns_to_keep,
        chunked=True  # Lecture par morceaux pour économiser la mémoire
    )

    for df in dfs:  # Itérer sur chaque DataFrame généré
        # Limiter le nombre de lignes par morceaux si nécessaire
        if chunk_size:
            df = df.head(chunk_size)

        # Supprimer les doublons en fonction des colonnes spécifiques
        if flow_name == "R50":
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["nom_archive", "nom_fichier"])
        else:
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["nom_archive", "nom_fichier", "publication_date"])

        # Trier par la colonne "nom_archive" en ordre décroissant et garder la première ligne
        df = df.sort_values("nom_archive", ascending=False).head(1)


        # Ajouter les données traitées à la liste des lignes
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            rows.append({
                "grid_operator": "grid_operator",  # Adapter avec ta variable réelle
                "file_name": row["nom_fichier"],
                "file_size": None,
                "archive_name": row["nom_archive"],
                "parent_path": "parent_path",  # Adapter avec ta variable réelle
                "event_time": "event_time",  # Adapter avec ta variable réelle
                "upload_day": "upload_day",  # Adapter avec ta variable réelle
                "upload_month": "upload_month",  # Adapter avec ta variable réelle
                "extraction_date": row.get("publication_date"),
                "flow_name": flow_name
            })

    return rows

But it return this error:

[ERROR] ArrowInvalid: Schema at index 0 was different:
flux_identifier: string flux_label: string xsd_version: string
sender_identifier: string recipient_identifier: string creation_date:
string request_reference: string subscription_reference: string step:
string prm: string raising_date: string business_id: string horodate:
string metering_value: string believability_index: string
horodate_utc: timestamp[ns] archive_name: string file_name: string
business_u_finale: string horodate_local: string horodate_date:
date32[day] creation_datetime_utc: timestamp[ns] run_id: int32
integration_datetime: timestamp[ns] start_interval_run: string
raw_bucket: string
_change_type: string vs
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/var/task/lambda_handler.py", line 56, in lambda_handler
df = process_object(   File "/var/task/lambda_handler.py", line 218, in process_object
for df in dfs:   File "/opt/python/awswrangler/s3/_read_parquet.py", line 243, in
_read_parquet_chunked
table=pa.Table.from_batches(chunks, schema=pq_file.schema.to_arrow_schema()),   File "pyarrow/table.pxi",
line 3979, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_batches   File
"pyarrow/error.pxi", line 144, in
pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status   File "pyarrow/error.pxi",
line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status

I tried to cast all field to str. But it doesn't work.
Any help please ?

parquet file's chunks have inconsistent schemas, causing AWS wrangler and PyArrow to throw an error during chunked processing, i guess you will find a solution if you search it in SO for similar issue

I think what you want to use is ParquetFile.iter_batches. But if the parquet file doesn't fit into memory, the rows themselves won't fit into memory either.

Looks like a schema error. Probably one of the df in the dfs iterable. Try printing the schema of each df or post full error message.

really short "answers" like this (guesses, suggestions) are best made as comments on the original question
